InAppPurchase - android pending transaction
I'm struggling at implementing InAppPurchase for subscriptions on my Flutter app.
I have a subscription plan that a user can purchase, but when I test it from my licensed testing account, my purchase comes into the Stream as a PURCHASED item. But then, validating receipt on my backend side makes Google returning a subscription state of SUBSCRIPTION_STATE_PENDING.
Then, 2 minutes after it, in the Play Console dashboard, my subscription becomes a purchased one (I precise that my test card is not a slow one). But there's no notification on backend side, so I guess this should be handled on the app side..?
Did some of you already experienced that ? If so, how do you deal with it ?
